# Expect within bash script

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I am trying to implement an expect script into a bash script. Bear with me since I am fairly new to bash/expect.

Here is the expect script that works as intended:

```
log_user 0

file delete foo.txt

set fh [open foo.txt a]

set servers {xxx@server1 xxx@server2}

foreach s $servers {
spawn ssh $s
expect "password: "
send "PASSWORD\r"
expect "$ "
send "grep "something" /some/log/file.log"
expect "$ " { puts $fh "$expect_out(buffer)"}
send "exit\r"
}

close $fh
```

Now, I am hoping to include this expect script in a bash script but it is not working as intended.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

XYZ=$(expect -c "
file delete foo.txt

set fh [open foo.txt a]

set servers {xxx@server1 xxx@server2}

foreach s $servers {
spawn ssh $s
expect "password: "
send "PASSWORD\r"
expect "$ "
send "grep "something" /some/log/file.log"
expect "$ " { puts $fh "$expect_out(buffer)"}
send "exit\r"
}

close $fh
")

echo "$XYZ"
```

The error I am getting is:

```
command substitution: line 42: syntax error near unexpected token `('
command substitution: line 42: `expect "$ " { puts $fh "$expect_out(buffer)"}'
```

I'm open to any other ways to implement this! :)

Comment: In your original script, the variable `$servers` is expanded by Tcl, since the whole stuff is a Tcl program. In your second script, the variable `$server` is expanded by bash, and since there is no bash variable with this name, it is replaced by the null string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `/usr/bin/expect -c` to execute `expect` commands :

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/expect -c ' 

file delete foo.txt

set fh [open foo.txt a]

set servers {xxx@server1 xxx@server2}

foreach s $servers {
spawn ssh $s
expect "password: "
send "PASSWORD\r"
expect "$ "
send "grep "something" /some/log/file.log"
expect "$ " { puts $fh "$expect_out(buffer)"}
send "exit\r"
}

close $fh
'
```

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to pass variables to the expect code using this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Bertrand's answer is one way to solve your question, but does not explain the problem with what you were doing.

Bash attempts to expand variables inside double quoted strings, so your `expect` script will see blank spaces where you want to see `$servers`, `$s`, and `$fh`. Further, you have triply-nested sets of double-quoted strings going on that will cause all sorts of problems with parsing the arguments to `expect`.

It's a matter of opinion, but I think when something gets to a certain point where it's considered a program of its own, it should be separated into a separate file.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
log_user 0

file delete foo.txt

set fh [open foo.txt a]

set servers {xxx@server1 xxx@server2}

foreach s $servers {
    spawn ssh $s
    expect "password: "
    send "PASSWORD\r"
    expect "$ "
    send "grep 'something' /some/log/file.log"
    expect "$ " {
        puts $fh "$expect_out(buffer)"
    }
    send "exit\r"
}

close $fh
```

Make sure it's executable, and then call it from your `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/my_expect_script
```

(To do this really properly, you should set up public key authentication and then you can get rid of expect altogether by running `ssh server "grep 'something' /some/log/file.log"` directly from bash)

Comment: Also, the logging going on in your `expect` script could be done much more concisely on the `bash` side of things.