# Executing a script remotely through ssh using expect

Tags: ssh, stdin, expect, remote-execution

I am new to using `expect`. I try the code below and it fails:

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh user@host < script.ecma3  
expect Password: ;
send "******\r";
send "exit\r";'
```

anyone could clarify

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expect within bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353148/expect-within-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1

spawn -noecho bash -c "ssh -t user@host '<here-comes-your-command>'"

expect {
  -re ".*assword.*" {
    exp_send "$env(PASS_WORD)\n"
    exp_continue
  }
}
```

**Note :-**

1) Copy script to remote host before running it. passing whole script is not good thing to do.

2) to access enviornment variables in expect , `$env(variable_name)` is used.

In above example , for `$PASS_WORD`, i used `$env(PASS_WORD)` .